# cakephp Session object destruction failed error when firing several requests at the same time

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

when I try to fire several requests to my cakephp site at the same time I get this error:

```
session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed [CORE\Cake\Model\Datasource\CakeSession.php, line 720]
```

I have no idea where that comes from. These warnings are crashing my ajax-calls. 
Same problem in cakephp versions 2.5.1 and 2.8.5!

Here is the code for the lines:

```
public static function renew() {
    if (session_id()) {
        if (session_id() || isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            setcookie(Configure::read('Session.cookie'), '', time() - 42000, self::$path);
        }
        session_regenerate_id(true);
    }
}
```

line 720 is the one with the `session_regenerate_id`-command.

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) but I don't get a "headers already sent"-error.

System:
Windows Server 2012 R2
IIS 8
PHP v 5.6

Any ideas? I'm not very familiar with sessions to begin with.

Comment: Show us the ajax call you're making and the controller its arriving at

Comment: It is not just one ajax call it's all of them. Happens when I fire more than one call at a time.

Comment: `I have no idea where that comes from` seems like an obvious race condition - there is a session id, but another request deletes the session before regenerating the session id.

Comment: What can I do to avoid this? Should I stop the session from being regenerated? If so how do I do this?